# context-property of TABLE_PER_TENANT separate schema?

Tags: eclipselink, multi-tenant

Eclipselink multi-tenant: TABLE_PER_TENANT separate schema

```
<entity class="mypackage.Foo" >
    <multitenant type="TABLE_PER_TENANT" >
        <tenant-table-discriminator type="SCHEMA" context-property="xxx"/>
    </multitenant>
</entity>
```

Got the following error:

```
[EL Warning]: 2014-10-23 21:55:47.406--UnitOfWork(32326774)--Exception [EclipseLink-6168] (Eclipse Persistence Services
- 2.5.1.v20130918-f2b9fc5): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.QueryException
Exception Description: Query failed to prepare, unexpected error occurred: [java.lang.NullPointerException].
Internal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
Query: ReadAllQuery(referenceClass=Foo )
```

What should the context-property be? How is it be used?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I can't still comment so I am sending you this advice as answer. Look at my article [Multi tenancy with EclipseLink and inherited entities](http://www.mafospace.com/articles/multi-tenancy-with-eclipselink-and-inherited-entities). Maybe you are experiencing same problems as I had.